# Unable to upgrade mysql-server-5.7

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, upgrade, apt

When performing apt get upgrade, I keep getting below error on upgrading mysql-server-5.7

Below error:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Error occurred: Query against mysql.user table failed when checking the mysql.session.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 5
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Tried removing mysql-server and mysql-server-5.7, same error.
Also purging causes the same error

Comment: Question should be asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead i geuss

Answer (score 1):

you may try to remove package manually

```
su -c 'dpkg - P -remove --force-all mysql*'
```

then you need to rebuild rum database

```
su -c 'apt-get clean all && rpm --rebuilddb'
su -c 'package-cleanup --problems'
```

**Edit**

to backup all your databases

```
mysqldump -u USER -p --all-databases > /mnt/backups/all_databases.sql
```

Comment: Do I loose the current databases when doing this?

Comment: In any case I suggest you to first backup your db.

Comment: I did a VM back-up. Is there any option without using RPM? I don't have this installed. I could install it...

Comment: You can use dpkg

Comment: I did this, removed mysql-server and mysql-server-5.7. However, when re-installing again, I get the same error:
Error occurred: Query against mysql.user table failed when checking the mysql.session.